# How do I move emails into folders using the IMAP library in python?

Tags: python, gmail, imap, email, imaplib

How do I move emails into folders using the IMAP library in python?

Trying to move an email from one folder into another. I have the uid of the emails that I want to move.

Comment: Quick pointers: check `CAPABILITIES` for move, if available, use `conn.uid('move', ).  If not, use uid('copy', ...), uid('store', uid '\Deleted'), and uid('expunge', uid)

Comment: By 'IMAP library', do you mean the standard `imaplib`, or the 3rd-party `imap_tools`? I would recommend the latter.

Answer (score 1):

```
from imap_tools import MailBox, A
with MailBox('imap.mail.ru').login('test@ya.ya', 'pw', initial_folder='INBOX') as mailbox:
    # MOVE all messages from current folder (INBOX) to folder2
    mailbox.move(mailbox.uids(A(all=True)), 'INBOX/folder2')
```

Lib: https://github.com/ikvk/imap_tools

Comment: what about if you don't want to move every single email?

Comment: @brekker, example fixed

Comment: @brekker, use mailbox.fetch